# Is there any summary of Convention in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, convention

I start to study Ember.js 
and I know some of conventions like 'application.hbs', 'index.hbs' but I don't know what kinds, how many conventions exist..

And, As I searched google, I got name of conventions. I think there are too many conventions in Ember. where do I search in google?? I already read https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/getting-started/quick-start/ from tutorial to glossary. but... still don't know what it is..

If someone know any summary or any sites about the convention, please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Ember in its entirety is essentially a set of conventions. You simply have to learn them one by one by going through the guides and trial and error.

Comment: @torazaburo hm...When I read https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/getting-started/quick-start/ it, I just find some of conventions. maybe 5 things?? hm... anyway u mean I have to do one by one. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Routes and Pages

Ember applications are organized by pages (called `routes`).  Each page in your application will have it's own route, and a `route.js` as well as `page_name.hbs` template assosciated with it.  Any HTML written in the template will be rendered only on that page.

Your application will also have an individual `application.hbs`.  Anything placed in here will be rendered on every single page, so you don't have to copy code for something like a navigation bar.

All of the various pages are mapped to URLs in your application router (`router.js`).  Below is an example of a route map:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('home', { path: '/' });
    this.route('page1', { path: '/pathToPage1' });
    this.route('page2', { path: '/pathToPage2' });
});
```

#### Optional Pod Styles

Not entirely sure what you mean by convention, but at the highest possible level there are 2 widely used ways to organize an ember app.

1. By default, ember groups your application files based on type, with
   all of the styles in a `styles/` folder, templates in a `templates/`
   folder, component templates in `components/templates/` etc.
2. The alternative method is to use `pod-styles`, where your
   application is organized by component (grouping templates (.hbs),
   styles (.css), and routes (.js) ).  Refer to this awesome tutorial
   for help with that: http://www.programwitherik.com/ember-pods/

[image]

#### Handlebars Templating

Ember uses the [Handlebars templating library](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/handlebars-basics/) to power the UI, and is used to declare components, helpers, etc.  Handlebars works perfectly with HTML, however, and the 2 languages can be used in the same file without conflict.

---

Comment: hm.. Thanks. I can guess what you say. but my boss give me the work to make a summary of conventions. but I don't know what exactly conventions. As I know, first one of convention is Application.hbs. ( `When application.hbs exists, anything you put in it is shown for every page in the application.` ) like this. maybe my boss want summary of conventions excel file. but... I don't know what i write... lol anyway could u explain me about conventions in detail..? I searche it in google, but I couldn't find it... Thanks!

Comment: I have added a section about routes and pages explaining `application.hbs` and some related things.

Comment: hm...Thanks!! It is really helpful to me. but I can't find all of the conventions. Do i just try to do one by one in Ember?? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "convention"?

Comment: I mean.. 'Convention over configuration' Conventions
::https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration

Comment: and one of the example is 'naming conventions' :: https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#naming-conventions